# Unable to convert .xlsx to .csv through Power shell in windows server 2012

Tags: powershell

I have created below function in Powershell to convert an .xlsx file into .csv ,the script is running in windows server 2012 machine.The script is getting complete without any error but it not doing the conversion.When same script I have tried in win 10 machine its working perfectly.Can you please confirm how to fix this issue.Is it due to server OS as excel is not installed in it ?

```
function xlsx_to_csv($xlinput,$csvout) {
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$xlinput") 
$Workbook.SaveAs("$csvout",6)
$excel.Quit()
}
xlsx_to_csv $yest_xl_in $yest_csv_in
```

$yest_xl_in and $yest_csv_in are the xlsx and csv file locations.

Comment: Try to change $excel.DisplayAlerts to $true and see if you get any errors.

Comment: _"Is it due to server OS as excel is not installed in it"_ - if Excel is not installed, this will not work as you cannot create the Excel ComObject.

Comment: @gms0ulman, first I thought of that too. But it clearly states "script is getting complete without any error".

Comment: @KirillPashkov it does indeed but that makes me wonder if it's silently error-ing...  if there is no Excel installation, don't see how an Excel ComObject can be created.

Comment: @KirillPashkov I have tested the function with $true.Its just completed without any error message.I am not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: Tested with changing the file locations to another machine where excel installed but still same issue.No conversion happening there either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elegant function to convert an `XLSX` file into a `csv`. I have been using it for quite some time now and it has never let me down, yet! :)

```
function Get-ExcelData {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Worksheet')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [String] $Path,

        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='Worksheet')]
        [String] $WorksheetName = 'Sheet1',

        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='Query')]
        [String] $Query = 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
    )

    switch ($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'Worksheet' {
            $Query = 'SELECT * FROM [{0}$]' -f $WorksheetName
            break
        }
        'Query' {
            # Make sure the query is in the correct syntax (e.g. 'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
            $Pattern = '.*from\b\s*(?<Table>\w+).*'
            if($Query -match $Pattern) {
                $Query = $Query -replace $Matches.Table, ('[{0}$]' -f $Matches.Table)
            }
        }
    }

    # Create the scriptblock to run in a job
    $JobCode = {
        Param($Path, $Query)

        # Check if the file is XLS or XLSX 
        if ((Get-Item -Path $Path).Extension -eq 'xls') {
            $Provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
            $ExtendedProperties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'
        } else {
            $Provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
            $ExtendedProperties = 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'
        }

        # Build the connection string and connection object
        $ConnectionString = 'Provider={0};Data Source={1};Extended Properties="{2}"' -f $Provider, $Path, $ExtendedProperties
        $Connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $ConnectionString

        try {
            # Open the connection to the file, and fill the datatable
            $Connection.Open()
            $Adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $Query, $Connection
            $DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
            $Adapter.Fill($DataTable) | Out-Null
        }
        catch {
            # something went wrong ??
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
        finally {
            # Close the connection
            if ($Connection.State -eq 'Open') {
                $Connection.Close()
            }
        }

        # Return the results as an array
        return ,$DataTable
    }

    # Run the code in a 32bit job, since the provider is 32bit only
    $job = Start-Job $JobCode -RunAs32 -ArgumentList $Path, $Query
    $job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
    Remove-Job $job
}
```

Now to get your `csv` file, you can simply do -

```
$csvfile =  Get-ExcelData -Path 'PathToYourExcelFile\YourExcelFile.xlsx'
$csvfile | Export-Csv -path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\CsvFileName.csv -NoTypeInformation  #Save the csv file on your Desktop
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek for the script.I am not yet tested it but wondering it may not work as I need to run the code inside a windows server where excel not installed.

Comment: Then this won't work for you. This code requires excel to be installed.

Comment: Check [this](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSExcel-Intro/) and [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2014/06/02/get-excel-data-without-excel/).