# Trying to convert xlsx to csv with ImportExcel in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have installed the ImportExcel Powershell module.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyAEsZG21ao

Now I am trying to convert a xlsx to a csv file using the module.
Does anyone know the code that could do this?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622323/unable-to-convert-xlsx-to-csv-through-power-shell-in-windows-server-2012/49623674#49623674) out, if it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks Vivek will have a look at that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
Import-Excel "input.xlsx" | Export-Csv "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

For others, the source is here:

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/

Comment: Note the useful presence of the `[string[]]AsText` parameter to keep your date values dates. e.g `Import-Excel input.xlsx -AsText ColumnA, ColumnC`

Answer (score 4):

As the module in my original answer has since been abandoned, I'd recommend Doug Finke's fully featured [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/) instead:

```
Import-Excel C:\folder\file.xlsx | Export-Csv C:\folder\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

<s>If you use the [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) module instead it's as simple as this:</s>

<s>`Import-XLSX -Path C:\folder\file.xlsx | Export-Csv C:\folder\file.csv -NoTypeInformation`</s>

Comment: Do you need to have excel installed on the machine for that module?

Comment: Nope, Excel not required :) It's a great module.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try

Comment: PSExcel was started based on my ImportExcel  module by an excellent PowerShell scripter. They stopped work after they saw me continuing to add features.

Comment: How do I specify which sheet?

Comment: @Isaacnfairplay `Import-Excel "C:\folder\file.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Sheet1"`